# Unpacking a list into multiple variables

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to unpack a list of lists, but into multiple variables?

`scores = [['S', 'R'], ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y'], ['P', 'Q']]`

Into:

`a = ['S', 'R'], b = ['A', 'B'], c = ['X', 'Y'], d = ['P', 'Q']`

Seems like something that should be quite simple and yet I'm unable to find a solution that doesn't involve extracting all the individual elements into one big list, which is not what I want to do. I want to retain the 4 individual objects, just not stored inside a list or dictionary.

Looking for a general solution that might apply if the number of lists within the list / number of variables change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating variable programmatically is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables), rather use a dictionary:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

scores = [['S', 'R'], ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y'], ['P', 'Q']] 

dic = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, scores))
```

*NB. IMO it's still better to keep the original list.*

Output:

```
{'a': ['S', 'R'], 'b': ['A', 'B'], 'c': ['X', 'Y'], 'd': ['P', 'Q']}
```

Or, if you have a known number of lists, unpack them:

```
a, b, c, d = scores
```